# Fatou's Lemma conditions for strict inequality

Tags: measure-theory

Under what conditions do we have equality (resp. strict inequality) in Fatou's Lemma?

If the sequence $f_n$ is convergent, then it is obvious that equality holds. Is it the only case?

There are some examples for which the strict inequality holds but I don't know any statement which makes it clear under what conditions on $f_n$ inequality would hold.

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you assume that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} f_n =0$$ almost everywhere and $$\int_A f_n d\mu >c>0$$ for almost all $n$.